# Which problems can delimiting DB identifiers cause?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, delimiter

I've just found the following in the [Doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/configuration:identifier-quoting):

> Just because you CAN use delimited
>   identifiers, it doesn't mean you
>   SHOULD use them. In general, they end
>   up causing way more problems than they
>   solve. Anyway, it may be necessary
>   when you have a reserved word as a
>   field name (in this case, we suggest
>   you to change it, if you can).

Which problems may delimiting cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`` delimiters are not portable.
"" delimiters are more portable, but to get them working in mysql you have to enable ANSI mode.

Comment: He means: MySQL is the only DBMS that uses backticks ` as identifier quotes. The ANSI SQL standard specifies double-quotes " as identifiser characters. (MySQL will treat double-quotes as enclosing a string unless you specify otherwise.) Other DBMSs also have proprietary identifier characters; for example SQL Server uses square brackets [...] (although it will also accept double-quotes)

Comment: @Hammerite - but what does it have to do with Doctrine? I didn't specify this kind of quotes and I guess if I switch dbs they'll go away automatically. So basically you mean that as long as I don't store SQL, generated by Doctrine (who would do that?), the statement I quoted is incorrect?

Comment: No experience with Doctrine; can't comment.